# PHP GD set PNG image resolution with decimal

Tags: php, decimal, gd, resolution

We do lenticular printing and usually the resolution of the image we work with will have a decimal point.  For example,

```
$file_name = "example.png";
$resolution = 400.85;
imageresolution($image, $resolution);  
imagepng($image, **DIR** . '/'. $file_name, -1, -1);
```

When I open example.png in Photoshop the resolution is 401 instead of 400.85. Just this little discrepency can affect the visual effect of a lenticular print. Please help!

Comment: GD accepts integers. Imagick seems to accept floats, give that a try.

Comment: Imagick only sets decimals for TIF.  For PNG, Imagick also rounds to the next integer

Comment: Could the specification of PNG stipulate only integer is allowed?